# Use of <mbunit> in NAnt fails

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, continuous-integration, nant, mbunit

I got stuck up when I tried to run the Unit Test written using mbunit from NAnt. when I tried this lines of code in NAntbuilder.

```
<mbunit 
    report-types="Html;Xml;Text"
    report-filename-format="${test_results.file}"
    report-output-directory="${test_results.directory}"
    halt-on-failure="true"
    failonerror="true">
  <assemblies>
    <include name="${build.directory}\*Test*dll" />
  </assemblies>
</mbunit >
```

I got an error message

BUILD FAILED

./.../mbunit.build(26,5):

Invalid element <mbunit>. Unknown task or datatype.

I have copied the mbunit.framework.dll, quickgraphalgorithm.dll,quickgraph.dll to NAnt's bin folder.

Could you please any of you help me out to run the mbunit test from NAnt.

Thanks in Advance,

Ganesh

Comment: are you using MbUnit v2 ? try with a more recent version

Comment: I tried with Gallio version also and changed gallio instead of mbunit even it fails and shows the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

[This blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/astopford/archive/2004/11/15/257278.aspx) about MbUnit & NAnt lists the assemblies you need to copy to the NAnt bin directory. As far as I can understand from your post you also need:

- MbUnit.Core.dll
- MbUnit.Tasks.dll

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have copied the MbunitTasks.dll but coudnt find Mbunitcore.dll, after copying that file also I am getting the same error.

Comment: It seems in the latest version of MbUnit the MbUnit.Core dll is built into MbUnit.Framework dll, so then you should have everything you need (and I'm out of suggestions).

Comment: Last shot: Do you have a <loadtasks assembly="c:foo\MbUnit.Framework.dll" /> in your build file?  See http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/loadtasks.html for NAnt documentation on the <loadtasks> task.

Comment: You actually want to use <loadtasks assembly="c:\foo\MbUnit.Tasks.dll" /> since the Tasks assembly is the one that actually contains the NAnt tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the latest Gallio framework to run mbUnit tests from Nant, but there's no MbUnit.Tasks.dll file in that package. There's a Gallio.NAntTasks.dll file, but Nant complains that there was a "Failure scanning Gallio.NAntTasks.dll for extensions. Unable to load one or more of the requested types."